# please identify 5-Pin R1K SOT-23 Package

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, components, surface-mount, packages

[image][![like this ][top mark ][R1K]

in the topmark R1K

Comment: It could be several things. Please provide details about the circuit that it was found in. See [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6710/component-identification-question-guidelines) for guidelines on asking part identification questions.

Comment: It is written on the outer cover R1K

Comment: you didn't read the guidelines; -1.

Answer (score 1):

ADR03, 2.5V voltage reference from analog devices